# VB.Net creating a zip file and extracting from a zip file

Tags: vb.net

I have a file "C:\Users\Wangui Kamande\Desktop\social.txt" which I would like to compress into a .zip file the location "C:\Users\Wangui Kamande\Desktop".
I got the following code from the Microsoft site but I am not so sure about how to go about this. 
Is it that the file "C:\Users\Wangui Kamande\Desktop\social.txt" has to be in a folder?

The code from the mircosoft site is:

```
Private Sub btnCompress_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCompress.Click
        Dim startPath As String = "c:\example\start"
        Dim zipPath As String = "c:\example\result.zip"
        Dim extractPath As String = "c:\example\extract"
        ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath)
        ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the [`ZipArchive.CreateEntryFromFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh485720(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method to add individual files to a zip...

```
Using zip = ZipFile.Open("C:\Users\Wangui Kamande\Desktop\social.zip", ZipArchiveMode.Create)
    zip.CreateEntryFromFile("C:\Users\Wangui Kamande\Desktop\social.txt", "social.txt")
End Using
```

To extract individual files from a zip, there is the [`ZipArchiveEntry.ExtractToFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh485718(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method, but you first have to find the appropriate entry in the zip.  You could use LINQ to find the entry by name, as shown below:

```
Using zip = ZipFile.Open("C:\Users\Wangui Kamande\Desktop\social.zip", ZipArchiveMode.Read)
    Dim entry = zip.Entries.Single(Function(x) x.Name = "social.txt")
    entry.ExtractToFile("C:\Users\Wangui Kamande\Desktop\social2.txt", True)
End Using
```

The 2nd parameter to `ExtractToFile` is optional, and specifies whether to overwrite existing files.

Comment: Mark that works thanks. But what about extracting from the zip file

Comment: @AndreaTand The `ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath)` code you already have would work if you want to extract all the files in the zip.  Extracting individual files is a bit more work, so let me know if that's what you need to do.

Comment: Yes Mark that is what I want

Comment: @AndreaTand I've added an example for extracting an individual file.

Comment: Thanks Mark. It is possible to zip that file and give it a password. I saw the source code somewhere but i can't seem to find it now.

Comment: @AndreaTand I don't believe that the built-in zip classes in .NET support password protected zip files.  Perhaps [DotNetZip](https://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) or [SharpZipLib](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib) would meet your needs.